# how to substitute strange character in MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I've this request for substitute a character string like

```
SELECT 
REPLACE (REPLACE ( Dcpt.[desc], 'Compañía', 'Compañía /'), 'Producción', ' Producción /' ) 
FROM Dcpt
```

That works fine but sometimes the end user wrote Producción with the single letter o without accent. I tried to replace the letter `ó` with the meta character `_` or `%`. It didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Try: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670957/sql-replace-special-characters-with-value-from-another-table

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

`_` and `%` have no significance in `REPLACE`. These are only used by `LIKE` and `PATINDEX`.

Use an accent insensitive `COLLATE` clause (`AI`) to have `o` and `ó` treated interchangeably

```
SELECT 
REPLACE (REPLACE ( Dcpt.[desc] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AI, N'Compañía', N'Compañía /'), N'Producción', N' Producción /' ) 
FROM Dcpt
```

Change `CS` to `CI` if you also want case insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Follow:**

```
SELECT 
REPLACE (REPLACE ( Dcpt.[desc], N'Compañía', N'Compañía /'), N'Producción', N' Producción /' ) 
FROM Dcpt
```